# sed script to convert wikipedia links

Tags: regex, sed

```
Input: [[target|visible]]
Output: visible
```

Here's my try:

```
's:\[\[\[^\|]*|\(.*\)]]:\1:g'
```

(unesacped and spaced for readability:

```
's: [[ [^\|]* | (.*) ]]:\1:g'
```

)

But it doesn't work.

EDIT: Solved it:

```
's:\[\[[^]\|]*\|\([^]]*\)]]:\1:g'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use extended regular expressions with `sed -r`:

```
echo '[[target|visible]]' | sed -r 's:^\[\[[^\|]*\|(.*)\]\]$:\1:'
```

I didn't find out how to match `|` with basic regexps...

Answer (score 0):

Try awk, its more suited for this job. Split on "|" and then get the 2nd field. Simple as that. Remove those `]` as desired

```
$ echo "[[target|visible]]" | awk -F'|' '{gsub(/\]/,"",$2);print $2}'
visible
```

or any tools that does splitting of strings easily. eg Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ echo "[[target|visible]]" | ruby -e 'puts gets.split("|")[-1].gsub(/\]/,"")'
visible
```

Comment: `awk` is not available on the system this is ran on.